# How Wordpress Generates HTML for Blog Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to figure out how exactly Wordpress works around blog posts so that I can implement something similar in my web application. And this is probably some basic php, but I can not seem to find out exactly how to do this!

Typically you have a a URL like `http://www.example.com/blog/2012/01/27/some-title`. And I know that the file `http://www.example.com/blog/2012/01/27/some-title/index.php` does not exist. What is the path of action that Wordpress takes and any php settings that need to be set in order for the html for the blog post to be generated? Is it related to a 404 error page for missing / invalid url paths?

Comment: Any good MVC framework should be able to handle that sort of routing quite easily.  But I'll wait for a PHP expert to chime in with the exact answer you're looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Wordpress does -- and indeed many of the popular MVC frameworks -- is route ALL traffic to a single [**Front Controller**<sup>*wikipedia*</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) script using an apache .htaccess file. The component parts of the requested URL are then broken apart by the framework/CMS to determine what controller should be executed to return the requested content. The underlying details of how it determines where to route the request vary from framework to framework.

The front controller will generally handle error displays as well as it (or the determined controller) is able to decide if the requested resource actually exists.

So the path of execution will be something like:

1. Generate a request
2. Route request to the appropriate controller
3. Execute/invoke the controller -or- display an error if not exists for the requested resource

I believe Wordpress actually sucks up **ALL** traffic and points it to the front controller. This is great in the case of the average Wordpress user who knows little about PHP programming or .htaccess rules. However, it's generally advisable to allow requests that reference files or directories that actually exist on the server to still be accessed via conditions in the .htaccess file instead of routing them to the front controller like all other requests.

Comment: Exisiting files are served directly. Then Wordpress only has a single controller, it's called WP_Query. It fetches the data and sets up the global state in which the theme starts it's action to create the HTML output.

Comment: @hakre You just became my go-to person for WordPress knowledge. Hopefully I'll never be forced to work with it :)

Comment: That why people actually pay for support after some time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's done by a file named .htaccess
You can define many types of rules in this file, redirects as well.
The logig of this structure, is to make the urls filled with GET parameters more friendly.

ex.:
yourdomain.com/blog

Setting certain rules in .htaccess will actually call ex.:

yourdomain.com/index.php?p=blog

You can google .htaccess, or here is a simple example:
http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/

Answer (score 0):

The [codex entry on wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) gives a useful summary of this.

The short version is:

- As the other answers mention, WordPress interprets the "pretty permalink" with the rules in .htaccess.
- Then $wp_query takes the query variables, figures out what you want, and gets stuff from the database.
- The results are thrown into The Loop, which displays each retrieved post.