# Wordpress functions without include

Tags: php, function

I was looking in my wordpress files and code. There is a file called `functions.php`.
But how it is possible that in every file there are called functions without including the `functions.php` ?

I learned in school that you have to include files when you want to use something from another page.

I can't find something useful on the Internet. Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [@rdlowrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895378/rdlowrey)'s answer to [How Wordpress Generates HTML for Blog Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9040499/1779433)

> What Wordpress does -- and indeed many of the popular MVC frameworks -- is route ALL traffic to A Front Controller [[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern)] script using an apache .htaccess file.

So when you are accessing any page served by a WP installation, certain functions become available to you, since it's all passing through the same "start point".

To start following the trail, open up `index.php` in the root directory, and see this:

```
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

From there, take a look at `wp-blog-header.php`. It's loading `wp-load.php`. If there's no `wp-config.php`, it prompts you to install. If you do have it in your directory, notice it requires `wp-settings.php`.

In the settings file, you'll see explicitly where your theme's `functions.php` file gets added into the mix around line 318 (of WP 3.8.1 at least)

```
// Load the functions for the active theme, for both parent and child theme if applicable.
if ( ! defined( 'WP_INSTALLING' ) || 'wp-activate.php' === $pagenow ) {
    if ( TEMPLATEPATH !== STYLESHEETPATH && file_exists( STYLESHEETPATH . '/functions.php' ) )
        include( STYLESHEETPATH . '/functions.php' );
    if ( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions.php' ) )
        include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions.php' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful! I'll keep your post in a text file on my pc:D

Answer (score 0):

The `functions.php` file of the active theme is loaded everytime your wordpress site serves a page.

So any function you add there will be loaded and available to use in your template files.

Say your functions.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
function my_example() {
    echo "<h1>My example</h1>";
}
```

Then, in your `header.php` you can call that function like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php my_example(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

You don't need to specifically `include` (nor `include_once`) the `functions.php` file in order to use your just declared function.

Comment: An example: I have the file functions.php and the file page.php, i have a function on functions.php and i call it on page.php, how does page.php know that the function is made in functions.php?

Comment: It is not `page.php` that is in control of the situation, but the WordPress app itself, that is bootstrapped and load a ton of things to make your life easier. One of the things it loads is the theme engine, that eventually load `functions.php` and *after* that loads any template files such as `index.php`, `header.php`, `page.php`, `archive.php` and so on.